# meteor: make parameter of external script reactive

Tags: javascript, meteor, jointjs

In my meteor-application there is a button to change from user view to editor view. 
In this part I'm using JointJS as an external package for displaying and editing of diagrams. (`api.use('mxmxmx:jointjs-all@0.9.3');`)

In the user view the diagram shouldn't be editable. So I want to switch `interactive` from true to false and the other way round.

But in my attempt the variable isn't reactive: `Session.set('editor', true)` doesn't change the view immidiatly. I have to relaod the page to see new view.

How can I make this reactive?

```
var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;

Template.jointjs.onRendered(function() {

    var interactive = Session.get('editor') ? true : false;
    var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
        el: $('#canvas'),
        width: 801,
        height: 496,
        model: graph,
        interactive: interactive,
    });

});

<template name="jointjs">
    <h1>{{diagram.title}}</h1>
    <div id="canvas"></div>
</template>
```

**Update**

This doesn't work either, as the interactive var just take effect by reload the page:

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
    var interactive = Session.get('editor') ? true : false;
    var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
        el: $('#canvas'),
        width: 801,
        height: 496,
        model: graph,
        interactive: interactive
    });
});
```

Comment: wrap your code in a `autorun` and will rerun when the session changes

Comment: @MarkUretsky: Doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reading the Docs](http://jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Paper:options) tells us that we can pass a function to the `interactive` parameter:

> - interactive - if set to false, interaction with elements and links is disabled. **If it is a function, it will be called with the cell view in action and the name of the method it is evaluated in ('pointerdown', 'pointermove', ...). If the returned value of such a function is false interaction will be disabled for the action**. For links, there are special properties of the interaction object that are useful to disable the default behaviour. These properties are: vertexAdd, vertexMove, vertexRemove and arrowheadMove. By setting any of these properties to false, you can disable the related default action on links.

So you don't need meteor's reactivitity here, just set a flag that the function passed to interactive can check.  e.g.:

Session.set('CanEdit', true)

```
interactive: function(cellView) {
  return Session.get('CanEdit');
}
```

You don't need to use a Session variable (or other reactive data source), however by using one you could also update the template to visually indicate that you are in 'Editor View' or 'User View'.

Comment: Maybe I'm missunderstanding you. As the user could change the view dynamically without reloading, I think I do need reactivity. And this isn't be done by the function as this function would only be called one time initially

Comment: my understanding of the highlighted section above is that the function will be called in the `pointerdown`, `pointermove`, etc event handlers.  So function will be executed every time user attempts to edit the diagram.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I did understand that part in another way.